# How could I create a terminal window in the background?

Tags: vimscript

I want vim to launch rails console(it's like relp) within terminal windows when vim is launched on my project directory.
To launch rails console, I need to run three commands like below and it's tedious.

```
vagrant up # launch virtual server. 
ssh xxxx@example.hoge # ssh into virtual server
cd xxxx/xxxx/ && bundle exec rails c # launch rails console. It runs on virtual server.
```

I could achieve this by adding some vimscript to vimrc.

1. run `vagrant up` by `jobstart`
2. `:term` in `on_exit` handler
3. send the commands to the terminal by `chansend` in `on_exit` handler

But this approach has a problem. In this way `:term` create a window on the foreground. so if I edit files, they're hidden when `:term` is executed.

How could I create a terminal window in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the function `term_start()`; it creates a terminal window, which you can then `:hide`. Or, pass the `hidden` option to `term_start()`.

I suppose `:terminal` followed by `:hide` also works. `:vsplit` should not be necessary, as `:terminal` creates its own windows. If you want to avoid messing with the layout of the current tab, `:tab terminal` followed by `:tabclose` might be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't mention I use neovim. If I used vim, this solution is perfect!

Comment: Everything except `term_start()` should be portable between the two. IIRC neovim’s `:terminal` just opens a new terminal window…

Comment: there is `"hidden"` option to the function.

Comment: @MaximKim thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can work around this problem like this.

```
vsplit | term | close
```